# Espaço entre numero da matriz

Tags: c, matriz

Boa noite , sou novo no site e iniciante em Linguagem C ,sei só o básico por enquanto,tem uma questão que estou com dificuldade se alguém souber como resolver ficaria agradecido.Estou pegando a **MatrizE** e a **MatrizF** e somando uma com a outra , deu tudo certo na conta , o problema é que eu nao consigo deixar **espaço** entre um numero e outro, ao invés de ficar por exemplo assim : 3 7 5 fica junto assim 375, alguem sabe como resolver? Eu utilizo o Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, j;
    int matrizE[2][3] = { {0, 3, 6},{8, 4, 2} };
    float matrizF[2][3] = { {2.2, 1.6, 2.6},{0.4, 3.1, 6.4} };
    float resultado[2][3];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            resultado[i][j] = matrizE[i][j] + matrizF[i][j];
    }

    printf("\n***Primeira matriz*** \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%d", matrizE[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n***Segunda matriz*** \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%.1f", matrizF[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n***Resultado da soma*** \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%.1f", resultado[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só colocar um espaço após os %d e outros do tipo dentro das aspas do printf.

```
printf("%d ", .....);
```

Comment: valeu , vendo agora é bem simples , mas nao sabia hehe, obg.